# Android SDK set Authentication Type on APN creation

Tags: android, authentication, android-sdk-2.3, apn

I'm writing an app for a client that needs to customize his Gingerbread smartphones: problem is that I need APN to use PAP Authentication Type, but I can't find a way to set it programmatically...

I found out how to create an APN, but I can't figure out how to set the authentication type...

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, problem solved...

With aShell managed to open database and noticed that the field wasn't "AuthType" but "authtype"... it's an integer that can assume values between 0 and 3:

- 0 is for no authentication
- 1 is for PAP authentication
- 2 is for CHAP authentication
- 3 is for CHAP or PAP, whatever is available